# How to calculate a specific time complexity of inverse calculation of matrix?

Tags: data-mining, algorithms

I am a green-hand in calculating the time complexity. Given a calculation as follows:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{A^T}(\mathbf{AA^T}+\lambda\mathbf{I}_n)^{-1}\mathbf{b}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A}\in R^{n\times p}$, $\mathbf{I}_n\in R^{n\times n}$, $\mathbf{b}\in R^{n}$ and $\lambda\in R$.

Could some one kindly give me the complexity of the above formula in details? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Olologin can you share any references to understand how to calculate time complexities for complex equations? I want to understand the priority of matrix, inverse, transpose etc of different orders. Note: Since I am a new member here, cannot comment over your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you need complexity of this calculation in big O notation - it is: $$O(n^3)$$
Why? Because matrix inverse needs $$O(n^3)$$ operations, and it is biggest complexity here.

Multiplication matrix by its transpose is $$O(n^2p)$$ (Because for computing every value in the resulting matrix of size NxN you have to compute p multiplications).
Matrix transpose is $$O(np)$$ But you can ignore any complexities lesser than $$O(n^3)$$ (like matrix sum, transpose, or multiplying by constant) because their order of growth much lesser than order of growth of inverse operation.

[Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have to further ask that, in the case $p>>n$, the complexity is $O(n^2p+n^3)$?

Comment: @aaronyxt, Yes, in that case you can additionally take into consideration all fast growing terms with p.

Answer (score 1):

@Olologin is correct for very basic direct solves with no optimization, but there are optimizations that exist, so I wanted to add a few points...

A great many mathematicians spend their entire careers on speeding up and optimizing this problem.  So, the solution depends a lot on the composition of the matrix (`sparsity`), whether the problem is `convex`,  whether it is being solved `iteratively` or `directly`, and what algorithm is being used.

For lots of data science problems $O(n^2)$ and better solves are readily achieved.

Some common libraries include:

- Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines ([BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/))
- [LINPACK](http://www.netlib.org/linpack/)
- [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)

Here are some surveys of the subject:

- [General survey](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~cchen/CS6331/ch2.pdf)
- [Survey of Iterative Methods](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme324/saad.pdf)
- [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)
- [Conjugate Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method)
- [Direct Methods for Solving Linear Systems](https://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/csa/node37.html)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please kindly give some link of the related publications?